# How are multi-class losses computed in a Deconvolution Network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am wondering what is the math and possible code implementation of computing a multi class loss in a Deconvolution Network based on this [paper](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Noh_Learning_Deconvolution_Network_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf).

Basically, if we have an image that is fed into the deconv network, and subsequently upsampled or undergo a series of transposed convolution to give an output image that is compared against the annotation ground-truth, how is the pixel-wise loss between the output and ground-truth annotation computed?

My current guess is this:

1. We convert the original ground truth annotation into a tensor of shape `[height, width, 1]`, where there is only 1 channel. That value in that one channel represents the individual labels of each pixel. (e.g. 1-20).
2. The final output of the deconvolution network should have an output of `[height,width,1]` that is exact in dimensions as the ground truth notation.
3. We flatten the output and the ground truth to a shape of `[height * width, 1]`. We finally perform one-hot-encoding on the last channel to get shapes of `[height * width, num_classes]` for both the ground truth and output, and we can then perform a softmax cross entropy loss.

Is this the correct approach? I've not done any segmentation problem before  and I couldn't find how the loss was exactly computed in this paper.

Thank you for your help.